# Laptop monitor plus two external monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors

Is it possible to have all three screens active. My external monitors are connected throught VGA and HDMI.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10

Laptop Dell Inspiron 7720
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4000

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your hardware. Most laptops are not able to do so. Linux is able to, if the hardware is supporting this.